# What happens if user deletes their mail account associated with SE?

Tags: support

I use Gmail account to login to StackExchange communities. If I delete my Gmail account what happens to SE accounts? Is there any chance to login into StackExchange communities?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158086

Comment: Great!!.. thanks Molot. I didn't notice that link. If you feel my question is not valid here I'll delete it.

Comment: If you want to ask general questions about all StackExchange communities, http://meta.stackoverflow.com is a better place. And most of possible topics like this one are already covered there, too!

Comment: @Mołot While, MSO normally has the answers, our Meta is the first line of support for the users here.  People are free to ask these types of questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the link suggested by [Molot](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/16495/molot) (from first comment to my question). I found the answer from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158086/login-associated-with-stack-oveflow-account-got-deleted)

Here is the answer from that link.

> You may need to use [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/defunct), which is accessible via the Contact Us link in the footer of the Stack Overflow page. It's designed to be used when an OpenID provider disappears, but you're basically the same situation.
>
> If that doesn't solve the issue, email team@stackoverflow.com directly and explain your situation, giving your old email address (and your old userID number from your profile if you still have it).